# Associate entities with a slug in a common table

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I am trying to store slugs of different entities in one table.
Suppose we have two entities and tables, 'product' and 'blog', there is also a third table - 'slug' which stores their slugs. The table 'slug' has columns: `id`, `entity` (string ('product' or 'blog')), `entity_id` (id entries from the tables 'product' or 'blog'), `slug` (string unique).

I am trying to do this in the file App\Entity\Product:

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="slug",
     *     joinColumns={
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity", options={"default":"product"}),
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *     },
     * )
     */
    private $slug;
```

This code throw some error:

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@JoinTable" in property App\Entity\Product::$slug was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

In the entity manager 'product' and 'blog' I need getSlug and setSlug, as well as most likely addSlug - which will add to the table 'slug' the changed value from the variable `$title`, `entity_id` id of the entity, as well as in the column `entity` the line "product" or "blog" depending on which entity will be created

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that it does not know what `@JoinTable` is, try changing this line:

```
 * @JoinTable(
```

to this:

```
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
```

Comment: fixed, and new error: [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property App\Entity\Product::$slug does not have a property named "options". Available properties: name, referencedColumnName, unique, nullable, onDelete, columnDefinition, fieldName.
how can I specify the entity column and the exact phrase like 'product' or 'blog' ?

Comment: I think you would have to do that in the entity `__construct()` method, or in your formtype https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#other-common-form-features